# UICollectionView Spring Flow Layout with UIDynamics: minimum space between cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit-dynamics

Im trying to get this effect: http://cl.ly/0W2B2k0a3l2H

Im using this code, conferring a spring effect with `UIAttachmentBehavior`: https://github.com/noiis/SpringFlowLayout/blob/master/SpringFlowLayout.swift

Despite the effects are similar, there are some differences that I would like to cover. The primary is to maintain the **minimum space between cells**, tried in every way but could not get it.

I thought `UIGravityBehavior` might work better, but received several warnings from XCode against implementing different UIGravityBehaviors to many items.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I think you cl.ly link isn't there anymore — did you find a solution by now?

Comment: @StuFFmc The link is working: https://www.youtube.com/v/UEOMCOYEB2s?start=13&end=18&autoplay=1

No, I did not found how to do that.

Comment: @StuFFmc and LightNight, did you guys find a solution? Im still interested in reproduce this effect. Regards.